# Datatable realtime only works for few times, not work sometimes, was working before, but working anymore

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo, datatables

I wanted last five realtime data, which was working fine but stopped all of sudden , can't figure out the problem , let me tell you I have 3 scripts running in cron to update data in server(LAN), Datatable version - 1.10.13, have millions data but only using last five.

table fields include index at `created_at`.

The problem is that nothing few times data in datatable changes and then nothing happens.

```
<table id="dataTables-example" class="table table-striped example">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Number</th>
                  <th>TVC Name</th>
                  <th>License Plate</th> 
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>Time</th>
                  <th>Action</th> 
              </tr>
          </thead>

      </table>
```

Html above , following jQuery:

```
var table = $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
            "aaSorting": [],
            ajax: "./licenseData.php",
           "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "columns": [
                    { mData: 'slno' } ,
                    { mData: 'camera' } ,
                    { mData: 'license' },
                    { mData: 'dateNewFormat' },
                    { mData: 'timeData' },
                    { mData: 'actions' }
            ]
          });

          setInterval( function () {
            table.ajax.reload();
          }, 1000 );
```

PHP Code below:

```
public function realtimeLicenseDetails()
{

    $i=1;
    $r=array();
    $stmt=$this->_db->prepare('SELECT cameraName as camera,licensePlate as licensePlate,dateAdded as dateAddedOn,extra as extraData, fileName as fileName FROM license ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5');
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
        //set camera for json output
        $rData['slno']=$i++;
        $rData['camera']=$row['camera'];
        //set license for json output
        $rData['license']=$row['licensePlate'];
        //set date for json output
        $dateAdded = $row['dateAddedOn'];
        $dateArray = explode("-", $dateAdded);
        $dateNewFormat = $dateArray[2].'-'.$dateArray[1].'-'.$dateArray[0];
        $rData['dateNewFormat']=$dateNewFormat;
        //set time for json output
        $timeData = $row['extraData'];
        $hours = substr($timeData, 0,2);
        $mins = substr($timeData, 2,2);
        $secs = substr($timeData, 4,2);
        $extraDetails = substr($timeData, 6,3);
        $timeDetails = $hours.':'.$mins.':'.$secs.' '.$extraDetails;
        $rData['timeData']=$timeDetails;
        //set action html buttons for json output
        $rData['actions']= '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="/FTPSERVERDEV/images/processed/'.$row['fileName'].'" download="'.$row['fileName'].'"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a><button type="button" class="show-picture btn btn-danger btn-circle pull-right" title="Show picture" onClick="showPicture(this)" data-img="'.$row['fileName'].'"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></button>';
        $r[]=$rData;
    }
    $results = array(
        "sEcho" => 1,
        "iTotalRecords" => count($r),
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($r),
        "aaData" => $r
    );
    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

I am calling it in licenseData.php like this:

```
require 'includes/config.php';
$fileManager->realtimeLicenseDetails();
```

config contains nothing but object creation code and other unnecessary details.

Comment: Does your table have an index on `created_at`? Please [edit] your question to tell us more about what's wrong, and to include your table definition.

Comment: Hi Jones, codes where working fine before just all of a sudden it stopped working, and yes query works fine cause I have url where it returns data in json properly.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: `"sEcho" => 1` concerns me - you should be returning that parameter exactly as it was sent in the request, something like `"sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho'])`. I'm not familiar with PHP but that looks hardcoded. Not saying it's the cause of your issue but it's something that jumps out at me.